# phalcon set view template

Tags: php, view, phalcon

I have some problems with templates in phalcon. It doesn't render as it have. Here is an example of do method of action. Action called UploadSave.
And after this action I want to render my image/upload temlate.

```
     try {
        $hash = $this->request->getPost('hash');
        $File = $this->_getUploadedFile();
        $Validator = new ImageQualityValidator();
        if($Validator->isValid($File)){
            $Image = $this->_saveImage($File);
            $EnvCfg = self::_getEnvCfgDir();
            $cfg_data = $EnvCfg->getObject(self::MYPAINT);
            $this->response->redirect($cfg_data->host.'image/crop?hash='.$hash);
        }else {
            $this->getViewData()->hash = $hash;
            $this->getViewData()->validation_error = 'Image is invalid!!';
        }
    } catch (AMyPaintExceptions $Exc) {
        $this->getViewData()->validation_error = $Exc->getMessage();
    }
    $this->view->setMainView('image/upload');
    return $this->getViewData();
```

But result is white screen.
image/upload.phtml is not empty:

```
{{
   if( false == $this->is_already_image_uploaded) {

       echo $Tag->form(
       [
        "image/uploadSave",
        "method" => "post",
        "enctype" => "multipart/form-data"
       ]
    ); 
}}

<p>  {{ echo $Tag->fileField('my_photo');   }}</p>
<p> {{ echo $Tag->hiddenField(["hash", "value" => $this->hash]); }}</p>
<p> {{ echo $Tag->submitButton('Submit'); }} </p>
   {{ if($this->validation_error){ }}
        <p>{{ print_r($this->error_information);}}</p>
    {{ } }}
{{ echo $Tag->endForm(); }}

{{
}
else { }}

    Image has been uploaded already.
{{ } }}
```

{{ instead of

Comment: Please, read the [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/volt.html) on how to use Volt templating language. Your template is nothing but writing php along template and thats what I wont debug. Also your post is corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Phalcon selects the view that matches your controller and action combination. You can however overwrite this by using:

```
$this->view->pick('other-controller/other-action');
```

In your provided example you should replace the following line of code

```
$this->view->setMainView('image/upload');
```

with this

```
$this->view->pick('image/upload');
```

Refer to the [Phalcon documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#picking-views) for more information.

---

On another note, I notice that you are completely missing the point of the Volt templating language. You are mixing PHP syntax with the Volt syntax, refer to [the link](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/volt.html) that Yergo provided you in the comments.